# how to user action helper in a i18n key in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-i18n

How to use action helper in a i18n key. For example, the i18n key is

```
Please <a{{action displayList}}>click here</a> to display the list.
```

How to translate this properly with ember runtime(i.e handlebars uncompiled version)

Comment: I don't see anything related to i18n in the code you entered

Comment: This is an i18n property key. fb.clickhere.msg = Please <a{{action displayList}}>click here</a> to display the list. using loc helper available in gists, translation is done. The code in handlebars is {{loc  fb.clickhere.msg}}

Comment: Can you please update the question with lil more insight to your code, As per my understanding you defined fb.clickhere.msg = "<a{{action displayList}}>click here</a>" and you want to render this button using {{loc fb.clickhere.msg}}, If it is so you can do the same using <a {{action displayList}}>{{loc fb.clickhere.msg}}</a> where fb.clickhere.msg = "click here"

Comment: Translation should be done for the message completely. Complete message is "Please click here to display the list". The anchor portion is only for "click here". In the case mentioned by you, translation will be broken.

Answer (score 1):

It is been a while since this question was asked, but since I haven't found the solution anywhere, let me put my solution here. The way I solved it is using [Handlebars subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions). For your example it would look like this:

in translation file

```
var translations = {
    'fb.clickhere.msg': 'Please <a {{actionDisplayList}}>click here</a> to display the list.'
}
```

in Handlebars template

```
{{t 'fb.clickhere.msg' actionDisplayList=(action "displayList") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Handlebar helpers support returning `Ember.View` instance then the following defined helper should work

```
{{localizedView fb.clickhere.msg}}

Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("localizedView", function(value, options){
  // value = fb.clickhere.msg
  var localizedString = loc(value); // localizedString = "<a{{action displayList}}>click here</a>"
  return Ember.View.create({template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(localizedString)});
}) // Ofcourse you should define it before you can use this
```